# Issue with html5Mode in angularjs

Tags: html, url, angularjs, location-provider

I'm trying to remove `index.html` of the url using `html5Mode(true)` in angularjs, this is the code:

```
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'myApp.filters',
  'myApp.services',
  'myApp.directives',
  'myApp.controllers'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  $routeProvider.when('/home', {templateUrl: 'views/home.html'});
  $routeProvider.when('/about', {templateUrl: 'views/about.html'});
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);
```

If I dont write `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` the url shows:

> localhost:(port)/MyApplication/index.html

If I write `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` the url shows:

> localhost:(port)

`MyApplication` is removed of the url.
And I want the url shows:

> localhost:(port)/MyApplication/

What I'm doing wrong? What's the problem?

UPDATE:

How should show my `<a>` tags? Right now I have:

```
<a href="#/about">About</>
```

When I click on the link, the url shows:

> localhost:(port)/MyApplication/index.html#/about

I'm lost with this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please provide the code where you define the routes. (where you call $routeProvider.when())

Comment: @bekite I've updated the post, sorry for the delay. Greetings.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your application runs under `/MyApplication/` try to set the base path in your index.html and switch on `html5Mode`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="/MyApplication/index.html" />
    ...
```

See [Using $location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#hashbang-and-html5-modes).

Comment: i was expecting all hrefs like 'dir/file.jpg' to be translated to '/MyApplication/index.html/dir/file.jpg' but to my surprise the browser is doing '/MyApplication/dir/file.jpg'

Comment: the w3c doesn't appear to document this behavior @ http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-base-element or even @ http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#resolve-a-url

Comment: @Reto Aebersold And when you refresh web page ? problem still here. Using this mode requires URL rewriting on server side, basically you have to rewrite all your links to entry point of your application

Comment: @biology.info yes, that's what you have to do in a SPA