# AngularJS: html5Mode(true) causing 404 error

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to remove **#** tag on my app using `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`. It takes out the **#** but now I get `404 errors` for all my views.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']).
  config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', { templateUrl: 'views/home.html', controller: 'homeCtrl' });
    $routeProvider.when('/about', { templateUrl: 'views/about.html', controller: 'aboutCtrl' });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

}]);
```

Comment: Does not make a difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out if one is usung `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`. You have to set a base url (`<base href="/appFolder/" />`)... [according to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617293/issue-with-html5mode-in-angularjs?rq=1)

Comment: Using this mode requires URL rewriting on server side, basically you have to rewrite all your links to entry point of your application

Answer (score 1):

For .net Project you'll need to also need to add rewrite rule in web config.
Add below code to web.config & in head of single page section add  href is of path of your single page

```
<system.webServer>    <rewrite>
<rules>
  <rule name="RewriteRules" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
  </rule>
</rules>  </rewrite></system.webServer>
```