# while refreshing the page Angular js giving 404 errror

Tags: javascript, angularjs

After adding

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true
            //requireBase: false
        });
```

I am getting **404(not found)** on page refresh. What should I do to solve this?.

Comment: Possible duplicate [AngularJS: html5Mode(true) causing 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21973802/angularjs-html5modetrue-causing-404-error)

Answer (score 1):

You have to set a base url in your index.html file

`<base href="/folder name/" />`