# Remove # from URLs in angularjs using yii2 as server

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, yii2, yii2-basic-app

In anglarjs, I use $routeProvider to route various urls. Want to remove # from URLS but failed after trying all the established ways to do so (setting html5 to true with `<base>` option in main.php along with .htaccess).

I am using views/layouts/main.php from yii2 framework as standard page that instantiates ng-app.

Can you tell what steps should I follow...

When I run a url without hash, it returns 404 as it cannot find the route that it used to find after #

Comment: Please provide more details what have you done exactly. Like configuration of the provider, content of the htaccess. Normally this works: https://scotch.io/quick-tips/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `html5mode` to true. See details here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Also, you need to setup `base` attribute in your HTML, if you want to prevent 404 error. See the Stackoverflow answer here [Issue with html5Mode in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617293/issue-with-html5mode-in-angularjs?rq=1)

Comment: This is an incomplete answer without mentioning that it requires server side configuration also to work

Comment: The first link explains the html5mode and entire $location, including server side configuration in detail. For sake or brevity, I've not explained that here as the original question only asked about #. If there's followup on that, I'll include in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure $locationProvider and set html5Mode to true:

```
angular.module('phonecat', []).
  config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/phones', {templateUrl: 'partials/phone-list.html',   controller: PhoneListCtrl}).
      when('/phones/:phoneId', {templateUrl: 'partials/phone-detail.html', controller: PhoneDetailCtrl}).
      otherwise({redirectTo: '/phones'});

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

  }]);
```

you can see detail in this [link](https://scotch.io/quick-tips/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag).

This code works for me i hope it works for you too.